# relative path in Java for database

Tags: java, ms-access

am a new bee, just learning for fun. I want to know how to write a database connection code in netbean for access database, so I will not use the full path but just the root directory of the project. thanks

Comment: Just beware, the "working directory" isn't always the same place as the location of the Jar file. Having said that, the connection URL will depend on the database driver you are using but would follow the same logic as if you were trying to navigate to the location via the command line `relative/path/to/resource`

Comment: Hello Jude, welcome to SO. We are here to answer specific questions, yours is very broad and not very clear. Perhaps quora is a better place to ask